# Create a mutation which takes multiple values of an ENUM

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, graphcool

I've created a model that has a field which takes multiple values of an `ENUM`. How can I write a mutation which will allow me to add multiple values at once?

For example, I have a sign up mutation:

```
export const signUp = gql`
  mutation signUp(
    $email: String!,
    $name: String!,
    $password: String!,
    $attended: [USER_ATTENDED!]!,
    $role: [USER_ROLE!]!,
  ) {
    createUser(
      authProvider: {
        email: {
          email: $email,
          password: $password,
        },
      },
      name: $name,
      attended: $attended,
      role: $role,
    ) {
      id,
      createdAt,
      name,
      email,
    }
  }
`;
```

I would expect `$attended` and `$role` to accept multiple values.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. As it's written it seems like it would accept an array of values. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass multiple values by using brackets: `[]`. In your case, the variables in GraphiQL need to like like this:

```
{
  "email": "name@email.com",
  "name": "Name",
  "password": "secret",
  "attended": ["A", "B"],
  "role": ["ROLE_A", "ROLE_B"]
}
```

In Apollo, this should work:

```
const variables = {
  email: "name@email.com",
  name": "Name",
  password: "secret",
  attended: ["A", "B"],
  role: ["ROLE_A", "ROLE_B"]
}
```

More information about GraphQL variables is available [here](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/flexibility-and-control-with-graphql-variables-thaexex7av/) and [here](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables).